# Why does logrotate generate empty log files when using two wildcards in log path?

Tags: ubuntu, logrotate

Logrotate will rotate the logs but when it renames the file to .1 (and then subsequently to .2.gz, .3.gz, etc) the files are empty. I've tracked this down to the path specified in the log config file:

```
/hosts/*/log/*.log
```

If I change the above line to one specific directory such as:

```
/hosts/website-1/log/*.log
```

Logrotate starts working properly. Nothing else in the configuration is changed and I'm testing it using the command `logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.d/hosts`.

I know I can list multiple directories for the logs individually but it would be easier if the first line would work. Any ideas?